# Get ActionBarSherlock actionBarSize in Android 2.x

Tags: android, size, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock, and this XML line crashes in Android 2.x:

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Is there a way to get the ActionBarSize for ABS?  Something like this maybe:

```
?android:attr/actionBarSherlockSize
```

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `?attr/actionBarSize` which will work on all API levels.

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height"
```

Comment: I had problems with @JakeWharton's answer but this did the trick for me. My problem was a "You must supply a layout_height attribute." RunTimeException