# How to make Android style windowBackground accommodate action bar

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm trying to have a style with a background image in the top right of the screen.  I have this working with

my_theme_background.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/myThemeBackgroundColor" />
         </shape>
</item>
    <item android:top="70dp">
       <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bg_my_theme"
           android:gravity="top|right" />
    </item>
 </layer-list>
```

Style

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_theme_background</item>
 </style>
```

I have to use that android:top="70dp" to keep the image under the action bar.  But the action bar changes height on rotation.  How do I keep the image under the action bar in the xml without explicitly setting a top value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can retreive its height via the attribute `android.R.attr.actionBarSize`. For instance for Honeycomb and later:

```
android:top="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Or, [according to Jake Wharton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11673753/154306), for ActionBarSherlock compatibility:

```
android:top="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this saying it can't convert it to a dimension.

Comment: Which SDK level are you building against? Does it compile at all?

Comment: Minimum 8, Target 17.  I'm using actionbar sherlock.  The app compiles and runs fine.  I explicitly set the actionBarSize in the style and that works fine.  I just can't use it as the top value.

Comment: I gave it a shot, and you're right; I'm getting an `UnsupportedOperationException` that it can't convert it to a dimension. I'm a bit puzzled myself.

Comment: [This answer appears to suggest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13026919/154306) that it can only be read at runtime.

Comment: I know it's not the nice answer you're looking for, but you could alternatively write your own implementation of drawable and resolve the attribute as per the linked answer above.

Comment: I think the best solution at this point is to explicitly set the height of the actionbar so there won't be a discrepancy between orientations.

Comment: In this case, I would suggest specifying the dimension through `@dimens/action_bar_height`, and defining it in `values/dimens.xml` and `values-land/dimens.xml`. Personally I would probably write my own drawable.